# Javascript: includes return false while matching partial array element

Tags: javascript

Very simple example here:

```
var u = []
u.push("https://cloudinary.com/products/media_optimizer/web-performance-guide#get-started")

u.includes("https://cloudinary.com/products/media_optimizer/web-performance-guide") //return false
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: **Includes** checks to see if the value is included AS a value in the array, not if the value contains that string.

Comment: @imvain2 what should I do then? iterate then check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the array, checking each element.

```js
const search = (arr, fragment) => arr.some(v => v.includes(fragment));

const u = [
  "https://cloudinary.com/products/media_optimizer/web-performance-guide#get-started"
];

const found = search(u, "https://cloudinary.com/products/media_optimizer/web-performance-guide");

console.log(found);
```

Reference:

- [.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks! Though others provided suggestions too I accepted this because I also got a chance to know about `some` here.

Comment: Hi, It is strange that for a few entries, despite of they exactly match your `search` is returning false.

Comment: @Volatil3 Are you sure they exactly match? For example, hidden characters (non-breaking space, carriage returns, unicode control symbols) can make strings different without them appearing different. We'd need a more comprehensive sample set than what you have in your question.

Comment: I rechecked, one of them had a traling `/` hence failed, so technically your solution is still correct.

Answer (score 0):

The value you are searching for must be an exact match, and you are not searching for the ending `#get-started`

Answer (score 0):

You are searching the array for an exact match to your string.
You can use `.includes(...)` on the string in the array which will return true.

```
u[0].includes("https://cloudinary.com/products/media_optimizer/web-performance-guide")
```

Answer (score 0):

your error is to use the includes in an array, the method is for a string value

```
string.includes(searchvalue, start)
```

for this to work you need to iterate the array:

```
u.map(item => item.includes("https://cloudinary.com/products/media_optimizer/web-performance-guide"))
```